# Eclipse IDE 2023‑06 installation fails with Certificate error

Tags: java, eclipse, java-17

I'm trying install latest Eclipse version to work with Java 17. But the installation fails with below exception. I've tried pointing to OpenJDK 17 Temurin and also Oracle JDK 17. I've also extracted the cert from the link which it was trying to download the resource from and installed it in cacerts. Still, the installation fails with below exception.

```
[2023-08-30 18:20:24] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2023-08-30 18:20:24] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200/content.xml.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: That looks like you are using the Eclipse Installer, but an outdated version of it. Get the current Eclipse Installer or a directly a IDE package from here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ If you use the Eclipse Installer, better use the Java contained in Eclipse rather than a Java installed on your system.

Comment: @howlger I've used the latest installer from this link only. I've also tried pointing to the Java contained in the Eclipse installer (JustJ) too. Facing the same issue.

Comment: Your log says otherwise. Please tell the exact version number and the download link (the mentioned web site contains different download links which are updated every three months). What do you mean by _"I've also tried pointing to the Java contained in the Eclipse installer (JustJ) too"? What exactly did you do?